# Saving an image captured using ngCordova and Ionic (file service)

Tags: file, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I want to save an Image I captured using `ngCordova` camera plugin in Ionic platform. I know how to capture the image but the Image is gone when I reopen the mobile app. I want the user to be able to take a picture that replace an existing one and also to be able to override that picture if she/he clicks the button again.

My problem is I cannot use cordova file service and local storage to store the image.

Answer (score 0):

refer to [Store Image into internal Storage in Ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168688/store-image-into-internal-storage-in-ionic)